# Configure UIView in viewDidLoad or var's didSet

Tags: ios, swift

Consider this example of configuring `MKMapView`'s map type. Should it be done in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
}
```

or in the var's `didSet`?

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView! {
    didSet {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
    }
}
```

Both work, what's the Swift preferred way?

Answer (score 8):

They each have a different use.

If you want the `mapType` set every time the property is set, use `didSet`.

If you only want the `mapType` set once when the view is loaded, use `viewDidLoad`.

Given what you are doing I would say that `didSet` is the more correct choice here.

BTW - this has nothing to do with "the Swift preferred way". The same logic applies regardless of language.

Comment: I wasn't sure if Objective-C has a `didSet` concept

Comment: Sort of. You would override the property's "setter" method.

Comment: I also set my map delegate in didSet works a charm. Nice and clean set up. It is also discussed in this blog post http://natashatherobot.com/ios-a-beautiful-way-of-styling-iboutlets-in-swift/

Comment: Would the map be more guaranteed to be ready to use in `viewDidLoad()`? Technically `didSet` is called after `mapView` is assigned. Could there be other initialization that happened between `mapView` assigned and `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: If `viewDidLoad` is called before this `didSet` then it means the property hasn't been set yet when `viewDidLoad` is called. This can happen. Another reason to use `didSet` instead of `viewDidLoad`.